# Expotential growth of symbols in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would i be able to display a triangle shape that grows exponentially with each line?

e.g. if the user inputs 4 (for the amount lines) the output should display.

```
*
**
****
********
```

I am aware that i will need to use the for loop its just the math i'm struggling with and whether I need a nested loop or not

Comment: No, you don't need a nested loop

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
lines = int(input('How many lines?: '))
starCount = '*'
for i in range(lines):
    print(starCount)
    starCount *= 2
```